# What should I include in <head> for IE?

Tags: html, web

To work well in IE 10, 9, and 8, what should I put in my ?

I searched here and there, then I entered like below.
I want to make sure below codes are ok to use.
I didn't use any bootstrap, or any frameworks.

I used Modenizr.

Here is the code in the head.

```
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
  <html lang="en" class="no-js">

  <!--some meta tags-->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>               
  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/libs/selectivizr.js"></script><![endif]-->

  <!--link my style sheet here -->

  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" />          
  <![endif]-->

  <!--my other link and scripts here -->
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no way to answer this. a basic html page with minimal css doesn't need ANYTHING special to "work" in IE.

Comment: `<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->` this could really help when using semantic html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For versions of Internet Explorer 8 and above, this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7" />
```

Forces the browser to render as that particular version's standards. It is not supported for IE7 and below.

If you separate with semi-colon, it sets compatibility levels for different versions. For example:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=9" />
```

Renders IE7 and IE8 as IE7, but IE9 as IE9. It allows for different levels of backwards compatibility. In real life, though, you should only chose one of the options:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

This allows for much easier testing and maintenance. Although generally the more useful version of this is using Emulate:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

For this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```